# Fundamental difference between feed-forward neural networks and recurrent neural networks?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I've often read, that there are fundamental differences between feed-forward and recurrent neural networks (RNNs), due to the lack of an internal state and a therefore short-term memory in feed-forward networks. This seemed plausible to me at first sight.

However when learning a recurrent neural network with the [Backpropagation through time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation_through_time) algorithm recurrent networks are transformed into equivalent feed forward networks, if I understand correctly.

This would imply, that there is in fact no fundamental difference. Why do RNNs perform better in certain tasks (image recognition, time-series prediction, ...) than deep feed forward networks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that **training** is done using some trick, does not change the fact, that there is a **fundamental** difference in the **preservation of the network state**, which is absent in the feed-forward network.

The "unrolled" feed forward network is **not equivalent** to the recurrent network. It is only a markov approximation (to the level given by the number of "unrolled" levels). So you just "simulate" the recurrent network with **k step memory**, while the actual recurrent neural network has (in theory) unlimited memory.

Comment: The difference is basically that you have to stop deepening or unrolling the feed-forward approximation to the rnn aat some point, did I get that correctly?
That might be a theoretical difference, but in practice also the simulation of RNNs has have to stop at some point, which is exactly the same as stopping the unrolling at that point, right?

I still see no practical difference.

Comment: well, you are wrong here. In practise, simulation can be arbitrary long. Recurrent neural networks are used for **sequential** data. You do not "run network for k iterations and read the output". You run it once for each input data in the sequence, and as the sequence can get arbitrary long, you have arbitrary long memory, which is not true for the learning process.

Comment: you can simulate it for arbitrary long intervals, but it still has to be finite. Why can't I just unroll to this arbitrary depth?

Comment: You seem to fail to understand the concept of "potential infinity". Eveything is finite, our whole universe is, it does not matter. The point is, that the feed forward network would grow linearly with this value, while recurrent does not. So you train a **fixed size object** which can hold the state for arbitrary long. Think about it a bit. You build a network with "k" state history. And then it works... after "k" states your ff network has no more "memory", recurrent has. So you build "k+1" network, and have the same problem.Recurrent does not. Still do not see the **fundamental** difference?

Comment: With regards to the preservation of the state, can't we say the same for MLPs? Isn't the state preserved in the units of first and subsequent hidden layers?